# Polymer paper-icon-buttons and iron-icons hidden

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I can use the the map, device, av... icons but not the normal icons.
And of course the map icon
What should I do?

My imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset/iron-iconset.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
```

That code is not working correctly

```
<paper-icon-button icon="icons:account-circle"></paper-icon-button>
```

[image]

Comment: The code looks correct ([demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JKmQqZ?editors=1000)). You don't need to import `iron-iconset`, but shouldn't cause a problem. What symptoms are you seeing? Are there relevant errors in the browser console? Do you actually have those files present in your filesystem?

Comment: See if the element is registered by running `document.createElement('paper-icon-button').constructor`. If it was imported correctly you'll see `function paper-icon-button() { [native code] }` in the console. Otherwise it'll say `function HTMLElement() { [native code] }`, which means the browser doesn't recognize the custom element.

Comment: This is my result: paper-icon-button() { [native code] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**
Okay I got it. There was a file called **my-icons.html**.
In this file I had to add the my icons which I wane use in my project.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">

<iron-iconset-svg name="icons" size="24">
<svg><defs>
<g id="expand-more"><path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"/></g>
<g id="save"><path d="M17 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7l-4-4zm-5 16c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm3-10H5V5h10v4z"/></g>
<g id="create"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"/></g>
<g id="add"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></g>
<g id="arrow-back"><path d="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z"/></g>
<g id="menu"><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"/></g>
<g id="chevron-right"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/></g>
<g id="close"><path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/></g>
</defs></svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

cc: @spliter

Answer (score 0):

1. The imports look correct and they do work in Polymer 1.x.
2. You should check your console for errors - might be that there are some importing errors there (wrong path to your `bower_components` for example).
3. Check the rendered HTML in your dev tools. If you DO see something like:

   ```
   <iron-icon id="icon" class="…">
       <svg…>…</svg>
   </iron-icon>
   ```

then there is a high chance the icon is not shown because of some CSS issues. So while your dev tools are opened check the CSS applied to your elements to identify the problem.

Comment: there is no <svg>..</svg> inside the iron-icon and no errors

Comment: @Dominic try opening icon-icons.html in your editor and check that `<g id="account-circle">` is indeed there. If it's not, re-install `iron-icons`.

Just to make sure it's not some trivial issue like caching - сheck that `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` option in your dev tools settings is enabled.

Comment: @splitter Cache is disabled and I found <g id="account-circle"> in irons-icons.html

Comment: @Dominic then we should see the whole file for your element. According to what you're saying and considering that you are totally sure the paths to Polymer elements are correct there is no reason this should not work. Please update the question with your code or give a link to your file on some code-hosting platform.